# Initial robot pose with respect to map

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, mobile-base, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using `map_server` to load a map in `.pgm` format and visualize in RViz. I also load a simulated turtlebot and can see it in same RViz window. I want to move the robot using my cutom planner node while using information from `map_server` node. I can obtain robot's current pose from `\odom` topic. My question is what will be the transform between `odom` frame and `map` frame. My `map_server` configuration file (`.yaml`) is as following

```
image: map_obstacle.pgm
resolution: 0.01
origin: [-2.0, -2.0, 0]
occupied_thresh: 0.75
free_thresh: 0.20
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317973/initial-robot-pose-with-respect-to-map/) by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This depends on where your robot is spawned. In the end, the `pose` in `/odom` is only the dead-reckoning pose, i.e. estimated from wheel revolutions.

What you would need to do this properly is some kind of localization algorithm that corrects the odometry drift using e.g. a laserscanner. `amcl` is a package that implements this. See [this section](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=melodic#Transforms) about the used/provided transforms.

---

**EDIT**

To fake a localization, you can use a `static_transform_publisher` ([documented on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher))  to publish the transform from `map` to `odom`. This can then be static, as we are assuming that the transfrom from `odom` to `base_link` is accurate. This should however be published by your robot's base driver / simulation.

Obviously, the transform from `map` to `odom` needs to reflect the starting position of your robot.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-03-08**:
Thank you for your response and I know that `/odom` data is inaccurate. Assuming `/odom` data as actual robot location, my question is how to know coordinate of the robot in occupancy grid map so that I can use my custom planner.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-08**:
see edit above

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-03-08**:
Thank you for the edit which is really helpful. I think what you said regarding transform between from `\map` frame to `\odom` frame is correct in the context of localization in unknown map. But since I am interested in `planning` when the `map` is known, I need transform from `\odom` to `\map`.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-03-11**:
@anirban well, one is the inverse of the other, so it doesn't really matter much. You can get the transforms in any direction you want with a transform listener...

However, as the ROS tf tree is using a [directed structure](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Design#The_system_doesn.27t_need_to_know_about_the_configuration_before_hand_and_can_handle_reconfiguring_on_the_fly), I suggest to use the [standard approach](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1442-L1444) of using `map` as parent and `odom` as child frame.

But I agree that [the direction of the graph can be confusing](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Design#The_direction_of_the_graph_can_be_confusing).

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2019-03-11**:
@mgruhler thanks for the clarification. Yes it is better to stick with the convention that `\odom` as a child of `\map` frame.